# Java: My ArrayList empties itself as soon as I empty the text file from which the ArrayList gets its contents

Tags: java, arraylist

I´m writing my own library in java, where you can save variables very simple. But I have a problem in changing the values of the variables. The ArrayList empties itself as soon as the txt file is empty.
My Code:

```
    public class SaveGameWriter {
    private File file;
    private boolean closed = false;
    public void write(SaveGameFile savegamefile, String variableName, String variableValue, SaveGameReader reader) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        if(!reader.read(savegamefile).contains(variableName))
        {
        file = savegamefile.getFile();
        OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        try {
            String text = variableName+"="+variableValue;
            stream.write(text.getBytes());
            String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            stream.write(lineSeparator.getBytes());
        }catch(IOException e)
        {}
        do {
            try {
                stream.close();
                closed = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                closed = false;
            }
        } while (!closed);
        }
    }

    public void setValueOf(SaveGameFile savegamefile, String variableName, String Value, SaveGameReader reader) throws IOException
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = reader.read(savegamefile);
        if(list.contains(variableName))
        {
            list.set(list.indexOf(variableName), Value);
            savegamefile.clear();
            for(int i = 0; i<list.size()-1;i+=2)
            {
                write(savegamefile,list.get(i),list.get(i+1),reader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here my SaveGameReader class:

```
    public class SaveGameReader {
    private File file;
    private ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    public String getValueOf(SaveGameFile savegamefile, String variableName)
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = read(savegamefile);
        if(list.contains(variableName))
        {
            return list.get(list.indexOf(variableName)+1);
        }else
            return null;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> read(SaveGameFile savegamefile) {
        result.clear();
        file = savegamefile.getFile();
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String read = null;
            while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] splited = read.split("=");
                for (String part : splited) {
                    result.add(part);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            boolean closed = false;
            while(!closed)
            {
            try {
                in.close();
                closed=true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                closed=false;
            }
            }
        }
        result.remove("");
        return result;
    }
}
```

And my SaveGameFile class:

```
    public class SaveGameFile {
    private File file;
    public void create(String destination, String filename) throws IOException {
        file = new File(destination+"/"+filename+".savegame");
        if(!file.exists())
        {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
    }
    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }
    public void clear() throws IOException
    {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file.getPath());
        pw.close();
    }

}
```

So, when I call the `setValueOf()` methode the ArrayList is empty and in the txt file there´s just the first variable + value. Hier´s my data structure:

```
Name=Testperson
Age=40
Phone=1234
Money=1000
```

What´s the problem with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `SaveGameReader.read()` method you have `result.clear();` which clears `ArrayList`. And you do it even before opening the file. So basically before every read from file operation you are cleaning up existing state and reread from file. If file is empty then you finish with empty list